# How to extend this code example to also include basic auth information?

Tags: clojure

I am very new to Clojure and was playing around with the following example from HTTP-Kit to do async get requests and then process all the results together when they are ready. In my case I also have to provide basic auth information, therefore the example given here (http://www.http-kit.org/client.html#combined) is not working and I havent found a nice solution how to pass in the additional basic auth information.

```
(let [urls ["http://server.com/api/1" "http://server.com/api/2"
        "http://server.com/api/3"]
    ;; send the request concurrently (asynchronously)
    futures (doall (map http/get urls))]
        (doseq [resp futures]
        ;; wait for server response synchronously
        (println (-> @resp :opt :url) " status: " (:status @resp))
    )
```

A single call with basic auth looks like this:

```
(def options {:basic-auth ["myuser" "mypwd"]})
(http/get url options)
```

It was easy to do sync calls one after another. With the async variant I do not know how to pass in the options in the right way. The code example uses map to call http/get with all the elements of urls. I need a way to pass in two arguments which are then applied to the http/get call. But as I just started learning Clojure I do not find the right way... I looked at apply / map / anonymous function...

Comment: Can you show some code that gets you past authentication as well? For example can `(http/get "http://server.com/api/1" "my-un" "my-pw")` be made to work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to pass your auth options to each `http/get` invocation in your `map` expression. For example:

```
(map (fn [url] (http/get url options))
     urls)
```

Or shorter version:

```
(map #(http/get % options) url)
```

Full example:

```
(let [urls ["http://server.com/api/1" "http://server.com/api/2" "http://server.com/api/3"]
      options {:basic-auth ["myuser" "mypwd"]}
      ;; send the request concurrently (asynchronously)
      futures (doall (map #(http/get % options) urls))]
      (doseq [resp futures]
        ;; wait for server response synchronously
        (println (-> @resp :opt :url) " status: " (:status @resp)))
```

Comment: Thx Piotr, I thought I tried this already, but it didn't work back then. Anyway, I will try it once I am back at my notebook. Thanks :)